# Attributes: Apache2 Cookbook [COOK-3900 branch] and Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

```
/*******************************************************************************
/ 
/ NOTE: This question is not valid any more, as there's a new version of the 
/       cookbook that solves the problem.
/
/*******************************************************************************
```

I just find out that the [official Apache2 Cookbook](https://github.com/onehealth-cookbooks/apache2) is broken for Ubuntu 14.04 because a problem with the new 2.4 version and that it is recommended to use the branch [COOK-3900](https://github.com/onehealth-cookbooks/apache2/tree/COOK-3900) modifying the `apache.version` attribute.

In `apache2/attributes/default.rb` file there's this line:

```rb
default['apache']['version'] = '2.2'
```

If I edit the cookbook and I change the value to `'2.4'`, everything works fine. But I'm branching the cookbook and I don't want to do that, so I create a custom cookbook and I insert that in the file `my_apache2/recipes/default.rb`:

```rb
node.override['apache']['version'] = '2.4'
include_recipe "apt"
include_recipe "apache2"
include_recipe "apache2::mod_php5"
include_recipe "apache2::mod_rewrite"
```

But chef tries to install version `2.2` and crashes...

I guess there is something I didn't understand well about attribute precedence.

EDIT: This question made me earn the [Tumbleweed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/63/tumbleweed) badge... Yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can add this line to your `my_apache2/attributes/default.rb`, no need for `node.override` in your recipe.

```
default['apache']['version'] = '2.4'
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Your solution works.

On the other hand, I am quite curious to know why my configuration doesn't work with this cookbook, is it an expected behavior? Node.override should have preference over default, isn't?

Comment: Can't say for sure why your line didn't work; I don't know if something else in your setup is causing this.